# Foreign Key Constraint in Laravel Migration

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, how can I add a foreign key constraint in a migration?

In the migration for `mytable` (which references `foreigntable`):

```
// add Column
$table
    ->string( 'foreigntable_id', 6 );

// add FK
$table
    ->foreign( 'foreigntable_id' )
    ->references( 'id' )
    ->on( 'foreigntable' );
```

Error:

```
[Exception]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'mydb.#sql-1a24_2
 1a' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `mytable` add constraint 
mytable_foreigntable_id_foreign foreign key (`foreigntable_id`) references 
`foreigntable` (`id`)) (Bindings: array (
))
```

I assume the problem is that `foreigntable` does not exist when MySQL tries to add the foreign key constraint to `mytable` (because the migration that creates `foreigntable` will only be run *after* the migration for `mytable` was finished).

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just found the answer myself.

Move the following from the migration for `mytable` into a new migration:

```
// add FK
$table
    ->foreign( 'foreigntable_id' )
    ->references( 'id' )
    ->on( 'foreigntable' );
```

Since the new migration will be run after the migration for `mytable`, as well as after the migration for `foreigntable`, both tables will be present at the time that the foreign key constraints is added. Hence it works.