# How to create a self-reference relationship (foreign key) in a Laravel migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations, laravel-schema-builder

I am starting with a self-learning project built on top of Laravel 5.2 and I have found my first issue: self-reference in a migration.

This is how the file `2016_08_02_024942_create_navigation_table.php` looks like (I have remove the comments for not make the post too long):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateNavigationTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('navigation', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('position')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('permissions')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('articles');
    }
}
```

And then because I have read several posts here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427391/laravel-migration-self-referencing-foreign-key-issue), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200981/how-to-create-migration-from-existing-database-in-laravel), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656207/foreign-key-constraint-in-laravel-migration) and many more I make another file with just the relation named as `2016_08_02_030158_add_parent_to_navigation_table.php` with the following code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddParentToNavigationTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('navigation', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('navigation')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('articles');
    }
}
```

But when I run the command `php artisan migrate` I got the following error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or
>   view already exists: 1050 Table 'navigation' already exists (SQL:
>   create table `navigation` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment
>   primary key, `position` int unsigned not null, `title` varc   har(255)
>   not null, `slug` varchar(255) not null, `permissions` varchar(255)
>   null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null,
>   `deleted_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate
>   utf8_unicode_ci engin   e = InnoDB)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists:
>   1050 Table 'navigation' already exists

Can any give me some advice? What I am doing wrong? I have see [this package](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) but I am not sure if it will solve my issue.

Comment: Have you cleared database before running it again?

Comment: Also you don't need add ```unsigned()``` for ```increments()``` but default it is unsigned (Tip)

Comment: @xdevnull I've run the command `php artisan migrate:rollback` and it clear the DB

Comment: please make sure it was removed. ```rollback``` is not enough prove, For someone reasons ```rollback`` may fail dropping table.

Comment: @xdevnull perfect, I've check and you're right, the `navigation` table doesn't get removed and for that it was failing, thanks for both tips.

Comment: Glad to hear that )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'navigation' already exists

Means **you have same table name in database**

So you need to verify, you don't have any **table** with that **name** in the database.

- Make sure no table name with the same name
- Run migration again

  `php artisan migration:rollback` Sometimes fails to drop table for different reasons.